# How to aggregate the sum for each distinct record on a given condition and get the result in an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to pass data to sparkline graph in Angular to show records with status "Open" for distinct SerialNumbers, but i am unable to push the results to an array.

Below query works but returns multiple documents, i want to have a single array with results.

**

```
db.Test.aggregate([{ $match: { status: 'Open' } },
{$group:{ _id: "$serialNumber" ,value: { $sum: {$sum: 1}}}}, 
{$group: {_id: "$_id",value:{$push:"$value"}}}])
```

**

For the below JSON data, how can i get result like "**value:[3,2,1]** or value:[{224:3},{221:2},{220:1}]". Where 3 is the total number of records where the status is Open for serialNumber=224, 2 is the sum of records where status is open for serialNumber=221, and 1 is the sum of records where status is open for serialNumber=220.

- JSON DATA:

{
    "_id" : 11,
    status:"Open",
    "serialNumber" : "224",
    },

{
    "_id" : 12,
    status:"Open",
    "serialNumber" : "224",
    },

{
    "_id" : 11,
    status:"Open",
    "serialNumber" : "224",
    },

{
    "_id" : 11,
    status:"Closed",
    "serialNumber" : "224",
    },

{
    "_id" : 11,
    status:"Open",
    "serialNumber" : "221",
    },

{
    "_id" : 11,
    status:"Open",
    "serialNumber" : "221",
    },

{
    "_id" : 11,
    status:"Open",
    "serialNumber" : "220",
    },

I am new to Mongo and need help, Hope the question is understood. Thank you.

Comment: please provide a sample of your expected result. Do you need only an array of count, or must they be associated with corresponding serialNumber too?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @matthPen. Need an array of count with corresponding serialNumber.

For example: [{224:3},{221:2},{220:1}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected result :  `[{224:3},{221:2},{220:1}]` : i strongly discourage to have values as field name : if you get as result a document (or array of documents) with the following structure : `result = {"224":3}`, you have to know the field name to access to value  (result.224 = 3).

My advice : use the [following](https://mongoplayground.net/p/38JCzo1uw4a) and access to result.results field to get your array (it will always retrun a unique document with results array)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: "Open"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$serialNumber",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      results: {
        $push: {
          serialNumber: "$_id",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
])
```

will return :

```
{
    "_id": null,
    "results": [
      {
        "count": 1,
        "serialNumber": "220"
      },
      {
        "count": 2,
        "serialNumber": "221"
      },
      {
        "count": 3,
        "serialNumber": "224"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @matthPen. This is very helpful.

Comment: Hey @matthPen, need help for two different queries. If you can help.

1)Get the count of value for each day using aggregation. 

In the same format as above, grouping by  date and the count of  "status:New" . If for example the status is new for 2 records on day1 and 1 record for day2. Result has to be day1 = 2, day2 = 3 ( day1 + day2),day3 =  day2+ day3.....

2) Get records based on week.
For week1: no.of records, week2 : no.of records,....based on week.